# Empty objects when loading arraylist from file

Tags: java, file, serialization, arraylist, deserialization

I have the following code to save an ArrayList of an object and then read it again. However it does not work, the read appears empty. How to solve it?

Some details: POInode implements seriazable; Looks like the data is correcly saved; The arraylist is non-static;

```
// READ & Write Class:

public GlobalWriteAndLoadPositions(){   
}
public void write(String folder, List<POInode> POIlist)  throws IOException {   

    int nextFileItarator = (int) Files.list(Paths.get(folder)).count();
    nextFileItarator++;
    FileOutputStream fout= new FileOutputStream(folder + nextFileItarator + ".txt");

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);      
    oos.writeObject(POIlist);
    oos.close();

    // the next line shows the arraylist full of objects and the File looks fine. (non-clear text file, but full of data)
    POIlist.forEach((a)->System.out.print("POI " + a.ID + " @ (" + a.getPosition().xCoord +" , " + a.getPosition().yCoord + ") | " ));
    System.out.println("\n");
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<POInode> load(String file)  throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
    List<POInode> listOfLoadedPOIs = new ArrayList<POInode>();

    listOfLoadedPOIs = (ArrayList<POInode>) ois.readObject(); // THIS LOOK WRONG, I MEAN,it is my guess

    ois.close();    

    // the following command shows the correct size list, but empty values!
    listOfLoadedPOIs.forEach((a)->System.out.print("POI " + a.ID + " @ (" + a.getPosition().xCoord +" , " + a.getPosition().yCoord + ") | " ));
    System.out.println("\n");

    return (ArrayList<POInode>) listOfLoadedPOIs;   
}

//Class usage:

if (Global.shouldSavePoiDistribution){

        List<POInode> listOfPOIs = new ArrayList<POInode>();
        for(Node n : Runtime.nodes) {   
            if (n instanceof POInode){
                listOfPOIs.add((POInode) n);                    
            }
        }

        GlobalWriteAndLoadPositions saver = new GlobalWriteAndLoadPositions();
        saver.write(Global.distributionFolder,listOfPOIs);
    }

// lets load a distribution IFF asked to
if (Global.shouldLoadPoiDistribution){

    GlobalWriteAndLoadPositions loader = new GlobalWriteAndLoadPositions();
    try {
        Global.listOfLoadedPOIs = loader.load(Global.distributionFile);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: is the file empty? any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: You need to learn using a debugger. That will save you hours and hours. Check what the list contains *before* it's written. Check what the file is when writing. Check what the file is when reading. Check what the list contains after reading. Only ask a question when you have clear answers to all these questions. "the read appears empty" is much too vague, and there is no way with the code you posted that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: No exceptions, runs fine. The begining looks like POInode descrition and them some encoded data. It is not clear text data. There are some KB... Looks that writes fine.

Comment: I suggest that maybe you are reading the wrong file or some similar error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the inherited variable. It was not Serializable as the class. I extended the original library.